# Is it possible to call Scripts.Render or Styles.Render from the code behind of an ASPX file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundling-and-minification

Is there a way to replicate the behaviour of the `@:Scripts/Styles.Render` helper from code behind?

If I reference the bundles by using the `BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl` method, then bundling and minification occurs even with `debug=true`. I've read other questions, and the solution seems far obvious, by using the previously mentioned helper. But in my case, I don't know the name of the bundle while in the aspx, and it's generated in runtime in the code behind.

So, I need to add the references in the head, from the code behind, and I can't find a way to do it.

Is there a way? Or will I be forced to do it in the .aspx file?

Comment: Why can't you just call these helpers in your codebehind to get the script/style references that you want to render?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yep!

This is what I do for Web Forms. This example adds resources to the `<head>` but also works with any control for which `Controls.Add()` works

For CSS:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal lit = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal();
lit.Text = System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/bundles/my_css").ToHtmlString();
Header.Controls.Add(lit);
```

For JS:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal lit = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal();
lit.Text = System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/my_js").ToHtmlString();
Header.Controls.Add(lit);
```

Also - since ASPX is a subclass of codebehind, you theoretically COULD get to the bundle name from ASPX by making it a protected (or public) variable in the codebehind (but you didn't post all your code so I'm not sure what you're up to exactly).

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out myself several days ago, but this was exactly the way I ended up doing it, by using `Scripts.Render` and `LiteralControl`.

Comment: how to render  <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />

Comment: @Ivan Lewis: [Read this for how to do bundles via server tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437800/how-do-i-use-asp-net-bundling-and-minification-without-recompiling)

Answer (score 6):

You could also just render the script inline

```
<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/my_js") %>
```

Comment: The OP specifically wanted it done from code-behind.

Answer (score 4):

This also may be of help for those who have come here later.

An alternate option without using a Literal Control:

```
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "MyJS", Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bundledJS").ToHtmlString(), false);
```

Comment: Another alternative. `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(Page), "MyJS", Scripts.Url("~/bundles/bundledJS").ToHtmlString());`

Comment: This may be a poor option as it doesn't render the tag in the header, so if there's dependencies above, it will cause javascript errors.

Comment: This option works ok but yeah, it doesn't give you control over where things are rendered. Though I believe you can use `RegisterStartupScript` , etc., for different behavior. Ultimately what I did was create my own server control to be able to do this declaratively. It's super sweet, see [my solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437800/how-do-i-use-asp-net-bundling-and-minification-without-recompiling/17689212#17689212)